# How can I import a data file into webpack using vue.js?

Tags: javascript, webpack, vue.js

For a Vue.js project I want to use Sqlite as the main data source using Sql.js and Alasql. The import should be done like this:

```
alasql(['ATTACH SQLITE DATABASE Chinook("Chinook_Sqlite.sqlite")',
        'USE Chinook', 'SELECT * FROM Genre'])
        .then(function(res){
          console.log("Genres:",res.pop());
         });
```

How can I include here the sqlite file using webpack? What configuration is required in webpack config? Thanks in advance!